# VBA - Deleting entire columns in excel if merged cell contains %

Tags: excel, vba

I want to go through the merged cells in row 3 and delete the entire column if the cell contains %.

I tried unmerge the cells and resize using the following code

```
Sub Macro2()
'delete column if cells contain %

Rows("3:3").MergeCells = False

For i = ActiveSheet.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

If InStr(1, Cells(3, i), "%") Then Cells(3, i).Resize(3, i + 1).EntireColumn.Delete

Next i

End Sub
```

But it deleted all columns to the right of the first cell that contains %

Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: Can you explain why you are resizing? Do you want to delete all the columns that the merged cell covered? `Resize` means just exactly that - so if `i` = 20 for example then you'll resize `Cells(3, i)` to 21 columns, which is presumably not what you want. Did you mean `Cells(3, i).Resize(,2)`, i.e. 2 columns?

Comment: The code works now. Thank you so much! I was confused with resize before :D